# If $A$ and $B$ are real orthogonal matrices of same order and $\det A+\det B=0$. Show that $A+B$ has determinant zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $A$ and $B$ are real orthogonal matrices of same order and $\det A+\det B=0$. Show that $A+B$ has determinant zero.

**My try**:

Here $\det A=-\det B$.
Also $AA^t=I=A^tA$, and $BB^t=I=B^tB$.
But I have no idea how to show $A+B$ has determinant zero from here.
Can I receive some help please?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe; it does answer correctly, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If we denote $\operatorname{det}(A)=|A|.$ Then since $|AB|=|A| |B|$ and $|A^t|=|A|$ we have,

$$|A+B|=|B||AB^t+I|=-|A^t||AB^t+I|=-|B^t+A^t|=-|A+B|.$$

Thus $2|A+B|=0$ which implies the desired result.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I did not know this question had an answer. So I answered it by myself.

Comment: See [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards).